# passing command line string lpszCmdLine to WM_CREATE in c

Tags: c++, c, winapi, winmain

I have a win32 app I wrote using c language.
I have implemented the use of command line arguments, which are captured into lpszCmdLine parameter of the WinMain() function.
This parameter can be accessed within this function, and WinMain is where I am currently processing the command line. (setting my various variables with those various command line arguments).
But I wish I could process my command line arguments inside WM_CREATE case of my callback function. Right now, some things are set to occur in WM_CREATE and I want them to occur differently based on my command line arguments.

Is it possible to pass a specific string to a callback function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can access command line from anywhere by calling [GetCommandLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156.aspx) winapi function.
2. Alternatively, you can save the passed in WinMain argument, and then pass it to CreateWindow() function as parameter (last parameter, lParam), then access it from within WM_CREATE handler as CREATESTRUCT.lpCreateParams
3. Alternatively, you can save it in some global variable and then access it from anywhere.

Comment: I think I like the simplicity of 3. the best - thanks!

Comment: @a1s2d3f4, You already have an effective global variable - the `GetCommandLine` function.

Comment: @chris, Except that I understand that GetCommandLine returns the full path to the app followed by commands, whereas I already have a parsing function that doesn't expect this path https://www.powerbasic.com/support/help/pbcc/winmain_function.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can access the command line from anywhere inside your process, calling [GetCommandLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156.aspx). If you'd rather have it in the form `argc`/`argv`, you can call [CommandLineToArgvW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391.aspx), and have the command line split up.

When using the CRT that ships with Visual Studio, the split up command line arguments are accessible from anywhere using [__argc, __argv, __wargv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn727674.aspx). Note, that only one of `__argv` and `__wargv` is populated, depending on whether the preprocessor symbol `_UNICODE` is defined when compiling the CRT entry point.